# Method inside object inside function

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm trying to write a method inside an object which is inside a function. Like this:

```
function createMountain(name, continent, heightInMeters) {
  var object = {
    "name": name,
    "continent": continent,
    "heightInMeters": heightInMeters,
    isHigherThan: function() {}
  }
  return object
}

var mountains = [];

var everest = createMountain("Everest", "Asia", 8849)
var montblanc = createMountain("Mont Blanc", "Europe", 4809)
var denali = createMountain("Denali", "North America", 6190)

mountains.push(everest, montblanc, denali)
```

The method `isHigherThan` should accept one mountain object as argument and return true if the mountain is higher than the one passed in the method, otherwise false.

```
everest.isHigherThan(denali) //true
montblanc.isHigherThan(everest) //false
```

How could i write such function? I'm quite struggling and not finding a solution. It should be also without ES6.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What problem are you having? Use `this` to refer to the first mountain, and a parameter variable for the second one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```js
function createMountain(name, continent, heightInMeters) {
  return {
    name: name,
    continent: continent,
    heightInMeters: heightInMeters,
    isHigherThan: function (mountain) {
      return this.heightInMeters > mountain.heightInMeters;
    },
  };
}
// let is from es6
let everest = createMountain("Everest", "Asia", 8849);
let montblanc = createMountain("Mont Blanc", "Europe", 4809);
let denali = createMountain("Denali", "North America", 6190);

console.log(everest.isHigherThan(denali));
console.log(montblanc.isHigherThan(everest));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would i write the method without using the curly braces for the parameter? I don't think i studied that yet.

Comment: @marbobby13 if you want full object then you can remove the curly braces it depends upon your usage